# Can(Javafx) I use ComboBox items to display a page? I need to link each option in the filmCombo combobox to an fxml file

Tags: javafx, combobox, scenebuilder

I need to link each option in the film combo to the fxml files and I need the options in the time combo to change when I click on the different option in the film combo.

```
@FXML
public ComboBox<String> filmCombo = new ComboBox<String>();
 ObservableList film = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Movie 1", "Movie 2", "Movie 3", "Movie 4", "Movie 5", "Movie 6", "Movie 7", "Movie 8", "Movie 9", "Movie 10");
//Listen for selection changes

@FXML
public ComboBox<String> timeCombo;
ObservableList time = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1:15", "4:15", "7:15");

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    filmCombo.setValue("Movie 1");
    filmCombo.setVisibleRowCount(4);


    timeCombo.setItems(time);
    filmCombo.setItems(film);

    filmCombo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( (v, oldValue, newValue)  -> System.out.println(newValue));
    timeCombo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( (v, oldValue, newValue)  -> System.out.println(newValue));
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are after and how you are stuck.

Comment: You appear to understand how to add a listener to the selected item, just load the appropriate page according to the newly selected item. What's the actual problem you're having? Also, don't use raw types (e.g. you should be using `ObservableList<String>`).

Comment: I'm not quite sure on how to do that, can you give me an example of how I can.

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox has OnAction like a Button.

```
filmCombo.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        String movieSelected = filmCombo.getValue().toString();
        if (movieSelected.equals("movie 1")) {//or use a switch statement
            time.addAll("time 1", "time 2");//set the items in the list for the time comboBox
            //add any other actions
            showRelevantScreen();//show another screen if needed
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how I can record each choice, for example if the user were to click on one of the choices let's say movie 1, it is automatically recorded for me to output on a different screen?  I'm really stuck on this part.